# possible amount of weight

Tags: algebra-precalculus

let us consider following problem

Courier charges for packages to a certain destination are $65$ cents for the first $250$ grams and $10$ cents for each additional $100$ grams or part thereof. What could be the weight in grams of a package for which the charge is $1.55$ $?

answer of this problem is  $ 1145 $,but i could not understand why,that is what i have tried

so as i understand  this  question ask that,if for example amount of weight is $850$,then  $250$   in this $850$ could be  $3$ times ,because $250*3=750$ and we have additional  $100$,so total amount of cents would be $3*65+10=215$ right?then how could be  $1145$? because $1145/250=4.58$ or  $4$ and remainder $0.58$ and $4*65=260$? or $2$ dollar and $60$ cent?please help me

please see this one
http://www.majortests.com/gre/problem_solving_test10

and this

http://www.majortests.com/gre/problem_solving_expl.php?exp=503131302431243234

Comment: If $x$ is the number of additional $100$ grams $$155=65+10\cdot x\implies x=9$$ 

Total weight should be $250+100\cdot9=1150$

Comment: but in $1150$  there should  be $4*250$ right?

Comment: beyond $250$ grams, we can utilize $10$ cent/$100$ grams which is cheaper than $65$ cents/$250$ grams

Comment: but there is question about minimization or what?

Comment: the title says: "maximum amount of weight".

Comment: i have  updated please,it is different one

Comment: Then $8<x<\le9$ and we know the total weight to be $250+100x$ So we can calculate the range of weight

Comment: Perhaps this is more of trying to understand the question more than anything else. If you have taken a taxi, this is exactly how it works. \$3 for the first 200m, and \$0.10 for the next 100m.

Comment: $3$ dollar for taxi is very expensive :D,but answer why is then $1145$ why we should not  rely on weight $250$?

Comment: i have posted  question link and it's explanation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, to clarify the question:

It says that if you ordered a package that weighed $250$ grams, it would cost $65$ cents and if it weighed more, then for every additional $100$ grams or part thereof, it would cost $10$ cents extra. The "part thereof" means that even if the additional weight isn't exactly a whole multiple of $100$ grams, the cost would be $10$ cents for each $100$ grams and another $10$ cents for the remainder. So for example:

If the weight of the package you ordered was $250$ grams, then the cost would be $65$ cents.
If it was $350$ grams, then the cost would be $75$ cents ($10$ cents extra for each additional $100$ grams). Now what if its weight was $400$ grams? The additional weight is $400-250=150$ grams. The $100$ grams of this weight would cost you $10$ cents and the remaining $50$ grams would cost you another $10$ cents. This is what the "part thereof" of your question means. So the cost would be $65+10+10=85$ cents. Similarly, if the weight was $450$, it would still cost $85$ cents, and if the weight was $451$ grams, it would cost $95$ cents.

Since the final charge is $155$ cents which is greater than $65$ cents, the weight must be greater than $250$ grams. The cost of the additional weight is then $155 -65=90$ cents. Now the $80$ cents out of these $90$ cents was for an additional weight of $80*\frac{100}{10} = 800$ grams. Thus the weight must be more than $800+250=1050$ grams. If we add another $100$ grams, the additional cost would then become $90$ cents, but note that it would become $90$ even if we it weighed an additional $1$ gram instead of the $100$ grams. Thus the weight of the package must be greater than $1050$ grams and less than or equal to $1150$ grams. Since $1145$ lies within this range, the answer is $1145$ grams.

Comment: ok i understood,only question what i had,why it could be for example calculate   weight in terms of $250$,thanks very much

Comment: @dato Are you asking why the approach you took in solving the problem is incorrect?

Comment: i would post question and answer

Comment: @dato Oh, I think the question isn't exactly what I thought. I'll edit my answer to incorporate this.

Comment: @dato Please read my answer. I've edited it.

Comment: i have seen it,but how can i clarify which answer is?could not be  there two possible answer?

Comment: @dato The question is asking, "what _could_ be the weight of the package?" This is the same as asking the possible weights that the package can have. As shown, if $x$ is the weight, then it must satisfy $1050 \text{ grams} < x \leq 1150\text{ grams}$. Out of all the choices given, only $1145 \text{ grams}$ lies within this range. If other weights were given that also satisfied this inequation, then those too would be solutions.

Comment: thanks very much,i have understood everything

Answer (score 0):

The total amount given here is $1.55.Let us first convert it to cents,i.e.,**155 cents**.Now it exceeds the fixed charge by **155-65 = 90 cents**.Till this point  we have total weight as **250 grams** corresponding to the fixed charge we deducted.Now additional **10 cents** are charged for every **100 grams**.This leads to the equation **(90/10) x 100** for getting the **extra grams** of weight.That gives us the amount **900 grams**.So now the **total weight** of the package will be **250 + 900 = 1150 grams**.But the amount here will be the **maximum possible weight** for which the amount will be **155 cents**.For the minimum possible weight we need to consider **801 grams** of weight as 800 grams of weight will lead to the total amount to be 145 cents.Thus the **minimum possible weight is 1051 grams**.So you will get your **answer** anything *between* **1051-1150 grams**.